# Deploy mule applications in RTF(Runtime Fabric) on-demand fashion

Tags: deployment, mule, devops, mulesoft

I have multiple mule applications deployed in RTF(Runtime Fabric), some of them are used only once in a month, So I want to free-up cpu cores by deploying those less consumed applications on demand basis (means automate the deployments just before it is going to consume and un-deploy later).

Could you please suggest, how can we handle this? or Any thoughts or approaches are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the reserved CPU to its lowest value (0.02 cores)? Meaning that the API will be always alive, but when not used it will scale down the CPU usage to this tiny percentage, would that work for you instead of undeploying/deploying on demand?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this. When app is not working it does not consume any CPU.